# Is Lightning still the way to go?

Tags: lightning-experience

1)
During our feasibility analysis for implementing a lightning based solution we found several drawbacks with the LC framework when compared to VF framework.

Has anyone replaced their VF with Lightning pages completely so far in any of their implementations ?

2)
Also for our new project we are thinking of training our existing SF team members on JS frameworks like Angular/Bootstrap/jQuery etc.

Should we go ahead with the training for the JS frameworks or the Lightning component framework is still the way to go ?.

3)
If Lightning component framework is still very much on then I assume that a moderate knowledge on Javascript is enough and we dont have to train our members on jQuery/Angular/Bootstrap etc...Am I correct ?

*PS : I know that non-programming questions cannot be asked on Salesforce.stackexchange which is why I have posted it in Meta. Do let me know if this kind of discussion question should not be posted here.*

Answer (score 9):

I slightly disagree with the above response, it's simply not that clear cut.

Lightning is still officially in beta. If you move to lightning now, you may hit road blocks. That's not to say that you CAN'T move to lightning, but there's a lot to take into consideration. I'm not sure that moving completely over to Lightning right now is feasible.

Lightning will take some time to mature, but eventually it will become the replacement that VisualForce so desperately needs.

In the meantime, it needs to be evaluated on a case by case basis. I've been building a Salesforce1 app recently for example, and I decided to use Lightning for this over VF.

This module on Trailhead has a great summary on when to use the various technologies:
https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev/lex_dev_overview/lex_dev_overview_future

For custom (desktop) development, I'm currently using VisualForce with the Lightning Design System (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/). There's also a module in Trailhead for this: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/lightning_design_system.

VF is supposedly going to be supported for the next ten years, so there's no urgent rush to leave it behind. My advice is to look for opportunities to use lightning and keep an eye on the release notes to see when the tipping point comes. I suspect it will be at least two SF releases away.

I was in a similar boat to you - I didn't have a great knowledge on javascript before starting with Lightning, so I invested quite a bit of time in some javascript courses on http://www.pluralsight.com before getting started with Lightning. Not that JS is that difficult, but if you've only ever worked with object oriented languages, it can be a bit jarring.

Answer (score 2):

1. Lightning is the way to go IMO. All you are doing by developing in VF is increasing technical debt and from what I've heard from SFDC they are advising everyone to halt development of VF for new projects.
2. Why not both? Knowledge in popular JS frameworks will also make your team more proficient at developing in Lightning.
3. I would say knowledge of jQuery at least would be valuable as it could likely end up being used in conjunction with Lightning.